# Change the datatype of the field in a table in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

In a Bigquery table, I am having data. I want to change/upgrade the datatype of one the fields in the table.

Current Table structure:
Name:String , FlatNumber:**Integer**,Address:String, Amount:**Integer**

Required Updated Table Structure:
Name:String , FlatNumber:**String**, Address:String, Amount:**Float**

Note: I am having data in the table

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need to transform the data and write it to a new table. You can then copy it back. For example, run this query:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  Name,
  CAST(FlatNumber AS STRING) AS FlatNumber,
  Address,
  CAST(Amount AS FLOAT64) AS Amount
FROM YourTable;
```

Then use e.g. `bq cp` to copy the table and overwrite the original one. If you have more columns, you can use `SELECT *` with `EXCEPT` or `REPLACE` to avoid listing all of them:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(FlatNumber, Amount),
  CAST(FlatNumber AS STRING) AS FlatNumber,
  CAST(Amount AS FLOAT64) AS Amount
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: This involves cost right? I was looking for something SQl DDL like ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype; in Bigquery

Comment: Yes, this would involve a cost. The other option would be to create a logical view over the original table using the query that I provided and then just query that instead. You cannot change from `INT64` to `STRING` or `INT64` to `FLOAT64` in place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even if I create view won't achieve my requirement since I was getting data for the column amount as decimal going forward. If I have the datatype as integer in the underlying table then view as float it won't help. The only solution left out for me is to recreate the table and copy back the data.

Comment: Assuming that you are loading the data into BigQuery because you want to query it later - why not just pay the cost to run one query transforming the table, instead of going through a full re-load?

Comment: It is not about paying. I just checked for alternative ways.

Comment: Is there any Airflow Operator to update the column datatype ??